# Multiple Regex Search and Replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a simple script which will take the regular expressions from a file, and then carry out the searches and replacements on another file. This is what I have but it doesn't work, the file is unchanged, what am I doing wrong?

```
import re, fileinput

separator = ' => '

file = open("searches.txt", "r")

for search in file:
    pattern, replacement = search.split(separator)
    pattern = 'r"""' + pattern + '"""'
    replacement = 'r"""' + replacement + '"""'
    for line in fileinput.input("test.txt", inplace=1):
        line = re.sub(pattern, replacement, line)
        print(line, end="")
```

The file *searches.txt* looks like this:

```
<p (class="test">.+?)</p> => <h1 \1</h1>
(<p class="not">).+?(</p>) => \1This was changed by the script\2
```

and *test.txt* like this:

```
<p class="test">This is an element with the test class</p>
<p class="not">This is an element without the test class</p>
<p class="test">This is another element with the test class</p>
```

I did a test to see if it's getting the expression from the file correctly:

```
>>> separator = ' => '
>>> file = open("searches.txt", "r")
>>> for search in file:
...     pattern, replacement = search.split(separator)
...     pattern = 'r"""' + pattern + '"""'
...     replacement = 'r"""' + replacement + '"""'
...     print(pattern)
...     print(replacement)
... 
r"""<p (class="test">.+?)</p>"""
r"""<h1 \1</h1>
"""
r"""(<p class="not">).+?(</p>)"""
r"""\1This was changed by the script\2"""
```

The closing triple quotes on the first *replacement* are on a newline for some reason, could this be the cause of my problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of the triple quotes?  Why are you adding them to the pattern?

Comment: The purpose is to (along with the _r_) reduce the amount of escaping I will have to do within the pattern in, for example with the quotes around "test" and "not" in the patterns. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something.  In python `r"""..."""` stands for a raw-string which does reduce the amount of escaping you need to do when working in a python script.  However, if you're reading data from a file, python will read it as a sequence of characters and it won't interpret the string `\n` in the file as a newline, it will just be those 2 characters.  In effect, when you read the strings from a file, they're already "raw"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need

```
pattern = 'r"""' + pattern + '"""'
```

In the call to re.sub, `pattern` should be the actual regex. So `<p (class="test">.+?)</p>`. When you wrap all those double quotes around it, it makes it so that the pattern never matches the text in your file.

Even though you seem to have seen code like this:

```
replaced = re.sub(r"""\w+""", '-')
```

In that case, the `r"""` indicates to the python interpreter that you're talking about a "raw" multiline string, or a string that should not have backslash sequences replaced (such as \n replaced with newline). Programmers often use "raw" strings in python to quote regex because they want to use regex sequences (like `\w` above) without having to quote the backslash. Without a raw string, the regex would have to be `'\\w+'`, which gets confusing.

However in any case, you don't need the triple double quotes at all. The last code phrase could simply have been written:

```
replaced = re.sub(r'\w+', '-')
```

Finally, your other problem is that your input file has newlines in it, separating each case of pattern => replacement. So really it's "pattern => replacement\n" and the trailing newline follows your replacement variable. Try doing:

```
for search in file:
    search = search.rstrip() #Remove the trailing \n from the input
    pattern, replacement = search.split(separator)
```

Comment: I marked this one as accepted as it's more detailed, thank you. Compared with the other answer though, what's the difference between .strip and .rstrip?

Comment: rstrip removes characters (whitespace by default) from the right of the string, whereas strip() removes whitespace on either side. See: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip

Answer (score 1):

Two observations:

1) Use `.strip()` when reading the file like so:

```
pattern, replacement = search.strip().split(separator)
```

This will remove the `\n` from the file

2) Use [re.escape()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) rather than the r"""+ str +""" form you are using if you intend to escape regex meta characters from the pattern